# How to select a kMean cluster as new Dataframe in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-analysis, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I have a dataframe with a few million entries, I used k-Means clustering and found that a specific cluster has very different centers from the rest. That is very interesting.

How can I select the entries that belong to this cluster to investigate them further? Can we select clusters as each being a Dataframe of its own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Spark ML or Spark MLLib?
See the example from https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-clustering.html#k-means -- `predictions` object contains what you are looking for.

Comment: I see, so using this with a filter I can create a dataframe only with the results of a given cluster. I guess my error is that I had the model based on the training data and I didn't know how to transform the original dataset.